# Nested select multiple options is not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a project using nested form to add multiple options on select but is not saving correctly.

**Tables:**

```
|users|
  |id| |name|      |lastname|
    1   Cristiano   Ronaldo
    2   Lionel      Messi
    3   David       Beckham
    4   Thomas      Muller

|ejecutives|
  |id|  |name|
    1    Mourinho
    2    Guardiola

|user_ejecutives|
  |id|   |user_id|   |ejecutive_id|
    1       1              1
    2       1              4
    3       2              3
    4       2              2
```

Controller **users_controller.rb**:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @ejecutives = Ejecutive.where('id=1')
  @user_ejecutives = @user.user_ejecutives.build
end

def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  @user.save
end

private
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name,:lastname, user_ejecutives_attributes: [])
 end
```

Models:

```
#User.rb
has_many :user_ejecutives
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_ejecutives  

#Ejecutive.rb
has_many :user_ejecutives

#UserEjecutive.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :ejecutive
```

View

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :lastname %>

  <%= f.fields_for :user_ejecutives do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'user_ejecutive_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
Select user ejecutives:      
<%= f.select :ejecutive_id, @ejecutives.collect { |e| [e.name,e.id]  }, {prompt: "Select 2 or more"}, {:multiple => true, class: "input-lg"} %>
```

Here is the demo project edited:

http://code.runnable.com/VvMYsfuOOwtvL870/nested-form-listbox-multipe-options

The issue is that is not saving multiple selections:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"sddasdas", "lastname1"=>"das","user_ejecutives_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ejecutive_id"=>["", "1", "2"] }}} , "commit"=>"Save"}
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `lastname1`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('David', 'Beckham',  '2016-03-28 19:43:18', '2016-03-28 19:43:18')
INSERT INTO `user_ejecutives` (`user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (68, '2016-03-28 19:43:18', '2016-03-28 19:43:18')
COMMIT
```

Is not saving the name selected in mysql I see NULL

Answer (score 0):

see the server console, it says

```
Unpermitted parameters: user_ejecutives_attributes
```

your `users_params` in `users_controller`

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :lastname, user_ejecutive_ids: []  )
```

change `user_ejecutive_ids` to `user_ejecutives_attributes`

may be it will works

Comment: Yes i did that but still not saving the option selected. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

`params.require(:user).permit(:name, :lastname,:user_ejecutives_attributes )`

Don't forget the colon (:user_ejecutives_attributes instead of user_ejecutives_attributes). It is a ruby symbol.

change in user model:
`has_many :ejecutives, through: :user_ejecutives`

change in ejecutives model:
`has_many :users, through: :user_ejecutives`

I would take collection select instead of select:
`f.collection_select( :ejecutive_id, Ejecutive.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'Please Select'})`

Comment: I did that http://code.runnable.com/VvMYsfuOOwtvL870/nested-form-listbox-multipe-options

Comment: Check my logs is doing the insert but is not saving the option selected. Is saving NULL

Comment: ejecutives_attributes: [:id,:name]